# git push origin master fail

Tags: git

I know about this were written a lot of notes,but they doesn't help me.

[image]

[image]

I have tried

```
    git push origin master:master
```

but this doesnt help me? any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to

```
git config http.proxy ""
```

or

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```